# How can you rebase to SVN without rewriting history in Git?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I work on a project that uses an SVN repo as the main repo. They make tags, the tags are what gets posted to the live environment.

So I cloned this both into an SVN working copy and into a local git repo. I track all my local changes using commits in my local git repo. When I've made substantial progress I go to the OS X Finder and drag-copy all the code directories from my local git repo, replacing the ones in my local SVN working copy. Then I SVN add the changes and commit that to the remote. That way all my millions of local commits don't end up on the remote server and I don't have to do any rebasing. (See below diagram.)

[image]

But still, I'd like to find a simpler solution. I read about how git has SVN support built-in, but [Git's site says](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion), "it’s generally best to keep your history as linear as possible by rebasing your work". OK so I tried this, I did a pull from the remote and had to do a rebase. The rebase involved about 20 conflicts I had to resolve, and then when it finished, all my commits were gone. Yeah, it's nice and linear now, but NO, that's not what I want, because I want to keep my local history. Furthermore then if I git svn dcommit, it's going to push multiple commits (two in the diagram, for brevity's sake) instead of just the one I want. (See next diagram.)

[image]

See, what I *want* to do is, I want to be able post the current state of my git repo as a single commit to SVN, and automatically have that reverse-fetch itself from the SVN server back to my git repo onto the Remote Branch. I don't want to have to do any rebasing, ever. If any other developers contribute something to the SVN, I'll merge those changes back into my master branch. (See final diagram.)

[image]

How do I accomplish what's pictured in this final diagram? Is it possible...?

When phrasing your advice, bear in mind, I'm still relatively new to both git and SVN. I use SourceTree and SmartSVN primarily but I am not afraid of the command line if that's the only way to accomplish what I need to do. For any dangerous operations, I tend to use the command line unless I'm 100% sure I know what my GUI tool is doing. But both of these still confuse me in certain ways. Thanks for any help.

Comment: +1 for "poof", although technically, those commits are still visible/accessible through the reflog.

Comment: I think I figured out an answer to my own question but I'm going to give people a bit more time to answer it and also to see if I was wrong :P